# Font corruption or fallback failure in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, debian, font-face, xfce

I have the following font breakage on many sites using Chrome 39 on Debian under XFCE:

[image]

It occurs on a variety of sites using custom fonts, all different. I can use developer tools to disable all font-family rules in CSS (most of the time) so that system fonts are forced, but this issue has persisted for at least a couple of months for me. I have run `fc-cache -fv` and I can't find anything that looks corrupted using fontmatrix.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed by upgrading to 40.0.2214.95 (64-bit). However, I don't think I actually reinstalled chrome from scratch before, so I can't conclude that is was a bug in the actual app.